# How to get the ranked cosine similarity?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity, pairwise

I have data analogous to the following:

```
TYPES|LABELS
Type1|Label1 Label2 Label4 Label5
Type2|Label2 Label5 Label6 Label8
Type3|Label2 Label5 Label6 Label7
Type4|Label1 Label2 Label4 Label5
```

Some context, I have code like the following that deals with how I visualize the clustering:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(df["LABELS"])
print("Count Matrix:", count_matrix.toarray())

cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)

fg = sns.clustermap(cosine_sim,figsize=(12, 12),method='average')
ax = fg.ax_heatmap
labels = [df.iloc[int(i.get_text())]['TYPES'] for i in list(ax.get_xticklabels())]
ax.set_xticklabels([],rotation=90,fontsize=14)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels,rotation=0,fontsize=14)
```

The third to last line is my somewhat hack-ish way of assigning the labels so they show me what everything corresponds to on a clustermap.

But what I also want is to see the types that have the strongest cosine similarity as a ranking in a DataFrame and I'm not sure how to do this.

It would be something like...(making some numbers up)

```
Pairs|Cosine_Similarity
(Type1,Type4)|0.8
(Type2,Type3)|0.7
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perm = permutations(range(0,len(df)), 2)
cor_dic = {}
for i in list(perm):
  if (df['TYPES'].iloc[i[1]],df['TYPES'].iloc[i[0]]) not in cor_dic.keys():
    cor_dic[(df['TYPES'].iloc[i[0]],df['TYPES'].iloc[i[1]])] = round(cosine_sim[i[0],i[1]],4)
df_cor = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cor_dic,orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'TYPES',0:'Correlation'}).sort_values(['Correlation'],ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df_cor
```